# Cannot Debug IOS Extension with Visual Studio 2022 on Mac

Tags: visual-studio, debugging, ios-extensions

Can't connect the debugger of Visual studio 2022 (Mac) to an IOS app extension, search and find [same problem](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/iOS-Extension-Project-is-not-debuggable/10361111?space=8&q=nuget&sort=newest) here.

I'm trying to build an App using C# for IOS with app extension and be able to use debugger. any help will be appreciated.

First I tried to create  an IOS share extension for my MAUI project on Windows using VS 20022 Ver 17.8.1 but with no luck [using this guide](https://github.com/dotnet/maui/discussions/3289)  it doesn't deploy to device. then I switched my project to Xamarin: it's easy steps here: first create a IOS dummy project then add a share extension using vs templates and add a reference to my extension, the project build and deploy but the extension doesn't work, I check all the things ( build identifiers, same minimum target version ...) but after three days I gave up on windows. so I installed VS 2022 on a Mac machine and on a first try it worked with Xamarin dummy project and a dummy share extension, but here I stuck on debugging the extension. can anyone help me, I want to create an IOS app with extension using C#.